# how to search a cell in a grid one by one when key press in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to search a cell in a grid  one by one  when key press in `c#`?

I was try the `key press event` several times but didn't work.

There was an exception .

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
         {
             if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(), true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
             {
                 list.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                 if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == list[i].ToString())
                 {
                     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                 }

                 //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                 /*if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected == true) 
                 {
                      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = false;
                 } */

                 // stop looping
              }
          }              
    }            
}
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to post the exception, waiting for it

Comment: i'm sorry   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"
  Source="mscorlib"
  ParamName="index"

Answer (score 0):

This line does not make sense, and also may result in <s>IndexOutOfBoundException</s> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` as not every row may be added to the list, so `i` may be larger than list count.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == list[i].ToString())
```

remove list and it should work:

```
private int  lastIndex;
private char lastKey;

private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(), true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                 if (lastKey == e.KeyChar && lastIndex < i)
                 {
                     continue;
                 }

                 lastKey = e.KeyChar;
                 lastIndex = i;
                 dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                 return;
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply.i was try that before .it will select all the rows that starts with the letter .i want to select one by one when it press.as an example when i press "A" it have to select 1st occurence.Then if i press again "A" i want to select next one

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Now we remember last selected row index and after key press we search for next not yet selected row.

Comment: thanks for the solution that u gave.it works for the second occurrence When for the third time pressing it will return .because in third time it will equal lastSelectedRowIndex and i value.

Comment: Okey, fixed once again :)

Comment: Ah damn, sorry was checking wrong side, it should be `lastIndex < i`

Comment: same as before , when it's running this part "lastKey = e.KeyChar;" is not executing ,thanx agin .

Comment: And once again my bad :/ (I need coffee badly!) last try I promise! Check edit.

Comment: same again .when pressing key once again it's not showing the result.it was showing only 1'st selected .thanx again

Answer (score 0):

at last found the answer .It will solve like this.

> ```
>     private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
>     {
> ```

```
        if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(), true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    if (lastKey == '\0')
                    {
                        lastKey = e.KeyChar;
                        if (lastKey == e.KeyChar && lastIndex < i)
                        {
                            int last = lastIndex;
                            lastIndex = i;
                            lastKey = e.KeyChar;
                            this.clearGrid(last);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (lastKey != e.KeyChar)
                        {
                            int last = lastIndex;
                            lastIndex = i;
                            lastKey = e.KeyChar;
                            this.clearGrid(last);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                            return;


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // int last = lastIndex;
                            if (lastKey == e.KeyChar && lastIndex < i)
                            {
                                int last = lastIndex;
                                lastIndex = i;
                                lastKey = e.KeyChar;
                                this.clearGrid(last);
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    continue;


                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void clearGrid(int l)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[l].Cells[0].Selected = false;
    }
```